# Difference between dynamically creating kobject using kobject_create_and_add and kobject_init_and_add function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

What is difference between dynamically creating kobject using kobject_create_and_add and kobject_init_and_add function?

kobject_create_and_add allocates a new kobject, while kobject_init_and_add initialize and the kobject passed to it.

```
struct uio_mem {
struct kobject kobj;
unsigned long addr;
unsigned long size;
int memtype;
void __iomem *internal_addr;
};
```

I want to use uio_mem in my show and store function, can i Use kobject_create_and_add?

```
static ssize_t test_attr_show(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr,
```

Is it possible to get uio_mem from the kobj?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is a bit old but anyway I wanted to answer it (it may be helpful for other people in the future).

First of all: `kobjects` are really well described (as a fundamental kernel structure) in ldd.3 (Ch14) as well as in documentation (https://lwn.net/Articles/54651/, http://lwn.net/Articles/51437/). Below I provide a shortcut based on these sources and my understanding. For more details please use these sources and kernel code.

Let's start from the end: why do we need `kobjects`?
They are kernel structures that provide way to implement inheritance for Linux drivers. Each driver related to `sysfs` should handle reference to `kobject` (you can think about it as a common ancestor).

The way how that is implemented: `kobject` needs to be embedded inside the driver structure (in your case struct uio_mem).

Code that works with kobjects often has the opposite problem: given a struct kobject pointer, what is the pointer to the containing structure?
In general programming tricks such as manipulation of object should be avoided and, instead use a `container_of` macro.

The way to convert a pointer to a struct kobject called kp embedded within a struct uio_struct would be:

```
// container_of(pointer, type, member)
struct cdev *uio_struct = container_of(kp, struct uio_struct, kobj);
```

Also with attributes by themself, you can find show/store function that didn't give you any kobject.

A good example that I have in mind is `virtio` driver:
see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/virtio/virtio.c?v=3.7

To answer your first question, we need to explain why we need `kobject_create` and `kobject_init`?

Main reason is that to run `kobject_init` you need to make sure that all fields are filled by zeros if that is not the case bad things can happen.
Function `kobject_create` doesn't have this issue: in implementation, it creates object using kzalloc and then adds it.
As I understand this function it is safer than init, but I don't see there a bigger difference between the two from a functional perspective.

Another thing to consider is dependencies between objects (if you have a different dependent kobject in your driver), then make sense to use first of all init and then create other objects see for example `iommu_group_alloc` (by using `kobject_create_and_add` you won't get any attributes by default but will be like parent/folder, init will create attributes by ktype)